# How do I insert a blank page between files using PyPDF2 pdfmerger

Tags: python

I am using this script to merge bill files so I can print 1 file.  The bills are 3 pages, so I need to insert a blank page after each file so the first page of the next bill doesn't print on the back of the previous bill.  How can I insert a blank page after each iteration of the loop for each bill file?

```
# If the file errors with "no module PyPDF2" then from command line, run pip install PyPDF2

import os
from os import listdir,mkdir,startfile
from os.path import isfile, join,exists
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

#Input file path and print the pdf files in that path
path = input("Enter the folder location: ")
pdffiles = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f)) and '.pdf' in f]
print('\nList of PDF Files:\n')
for file in pdffiles:
    print(file)

#Input the name of the result file
resultFile = input("\nEnter the name of the result file : ")
if '.pdf' not in resultFile:
    resultFile += '.pdf'

#Append the pdf files
merger = PdfFileMerger()
for pdf in pdffiles:
    merger.append(path+'\\'+pdf)
    # The line below hopefully will add a blank page between 
    merger.addBlankPage(w,h)

#If the Output directory does not exist then create one
if not exists(path+'\\Output'):
    mkdir(path+'\\Output')

#Write the merged result file to the Output directory
merger.write(path+'\\Output\\'+resultFile)
merger.close()

#Launch the result file
print('\n'+resultFile,'Successfully created!!! at ',path+'\\Output\\')
startfile(path+'\\Output\\'+resultFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

First add blank page to end, then merge them.

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter


def add_blank_to_end(files: list) -> list:
    names = []
    for f in files:
        pdf_in = open(f, 'rb')
        pdf_file = PdfFileReader(pdf_in)
        output = PdfFileWriter()
        output.appendPagesFromReader(pdf_file)
        output.addBlankPage()
        names.append(f'b{f}')
        outputStream = open(f'b{f}', 'wb')
        output.write(outputStream)
    return names


def merge_pdfs(files: list):
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    for f in files:
        merger.append(f)
    merger.write("document-output.pdf")


files = ['file1.pdf', 'file2.pdf']
with_blank = add_blank_to_end(files)
merge_pdfs(with_blank)

# delete extra files
for i in with_blank:
    os.remove(i)
```