# Multiply PDF pages from different documents, with blanks inbetween

Tags: python, pdf

I have been asked to create a PDF document consisting of (many) duplicate pages of first page of different documents. I need to have a blanks inbetween.

Example: given PDF documents `A` and `B` my new document could be

```
A1 A1 A1 ... A1  blank blank blank  B1 B1 B1 B1 ... B1
<---- N times->  <-- N blanks --->  <----- N times -->
```

Python is my initial go to tool, but not a requirement. Just don't have access to C etc.

I have the initial part working. My problem is how do I **add the blank pages** ?
PdfFileMerger has no property for adding a blank page.

I would prefer not to create a separate PDF document just for this purpose. I will not modify source PDFs to add a blank page as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72903196/how-do-i-insert-a-blank-page-between-files-using-pypdf2-pdfmerger)

I should notice that at the moment, A and B are single-page PDFs. But I could potentially be required to take a certain page from the source doc.

The library of choice is open, just found PdfFileMerger to be working.

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

merged = PdfFileMerger()

# example: 20 of each A and B
docs = [(20, "A.pdf"),
        (20, "B.pdf") ]

blankpagecount = 3

for p in docs:
    numpages = p[0]
    docname  = p[1]
    for i in range(numpages):
        merged.append(docname)
    # --- no property for adding blank page
    #for i in range(blankpagecount):
    #    merged.addBlankPage()

merged.write("mergeddoc2.pdf")
merged.close()
```

Comment: Yes @KJ but with the libraries I have tried, the file will grow quite a bit. Not as much as N pages * filesize though. Example: 2000 pages will be around 15 MB for a source of around 100 kB.  Not sure how PDF internals are wired exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super simple and super fast if you use PyMuPDF:

```py
import fitz  # PyMuPDF

N = 5
A = fitz.open("A.pdf")  # PDF A
B = fitz.open("B.pdf")  # PDF B
doc = fitz.open()  # output PDF

for i in range(N):  # insert page 0 from A for N times
    doc.insert_pdf(A, from_page=0, to_page=0)

for i in range(N):  # insert N blank pages
    doc.insert_page(-1)

for i in range(N):  # append page 0 from B for N times
    doc.insert_pdf(B, from_page=0, to_page=0)

doc.ez_save("output.pdf")  # save output with decent compression
```

**Note:** I am a maintainer and the original creator of [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/).

Answer (score 1):

You can run, for example:

`cpdf a.pdf 1,1,1,1 AND -pad-multiple 10 AND b.pdf 1,1,1 -o out.pdf`

where 10 is 4 (pages already done) plus 6 (desired number of blank pages).

Note that your future use of picking a page from each PDF is already incorporated here.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, there is no proper built in function, so here could be a workaround:

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

def add_blank_pages(merged_pdf, num_blank_pages):
    blank_page = PdfFileReader("blank.pdf")  # You need a blank page PDF
    for _ in range(num_blank_pages):
        merged_pdf.addPage(blank_page.getPage(0))

merged = PdfFileMerger()

# example: 20 of each A and B
docs = [(20, "A.pdf"), (20, "B.pdf")]

blankpagecount = 3

for p in docs:
    numpages = p[0]
    docname = p[1]
    for i in range(numpages):
        merged.append(docname)
        if i < numpages - 1:  # Add blank pages except after the last page of each document
            add_blank_pages(merged, blankpagecount)

merged.write("mergeddoc2.pdf")
merged.close()
```

What I did:
I defined a function  `add_blank_pages` that adds a specified number of blank pages from a "blank.pdf" file to the merged PDF. You should create a simple PDF file containing a blank page that you can use for this purpose. This function is called within your loop to add blank pages between the duplicate pages from different documents.

If you want to add multiple copies of each page from "A.pdf" and "B.pdf" before inserting the blank pages, you can adjust your loop accordingly. For example:

```py
for p in docs:
    numpages = p[0]
    docname = p[1]
    for i in range(numpages):
        for _ in range(duplicate_count):  # Add each page multiple times
            merged.append(docname)
        if i < numpages - 1:  # Add blank pages except after the last page of each document
            add_blank_pages(merged, blankpagecount)
```

To add three blank pages after the last page of both "A.pdf" and "B.pdf" in your code, you can modify it:

```py
# example: 20 of each A and B
docs = [(20, "A.pdf"), (20, "B.pdf")]

blankpagecount = 3

for p in docs:
    numpages = p[0]
    docname = p[1]
    for i in range(numpages):
        merged.append(docname)
        if i < numpages - 1:  # Add blank pages except after the last page of each document
            add_blank_pages(merged, blankpagecount)
        elif i == numpages - 1:  # Add blank pages after the last page of each document
            add_blank_pages(merged, blankpagecount)

merged.write("mergeddoc2.pdf")
merged.close()
```

If you want to add three blank pages immediately after "A.pdf" and not after "B.pdf," you can modify the code:

```py
# example: 20 of each A and B
docs = [(20, "A.pdf"), (20, "B.pdf")]

blankpagecount = 3

for p in docs:
    numpages = p[0]
    docname = p[1]
    for i in range(numpages):
        merged.append(docname)
        if docname == "A.pdf" and i == numpages - 1:
            add_blank_pages(merged, blankpagecount)

merged.write("mergeddoc2.pdf")
merged.close()
```

I gave you these four examples, because I was not quite sure about what’s fitting your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

PDF has some optimising features so here we have 15 pages 5 references to A1 and 5 references to B1  with 5 references to a blank between.

So that's roughly 1 KB per page for an uncompressed 2KB file of 15 pages.

The Major advantage of such a method is we can have 1 or 2 complex pages of graphics (Think forms, charts, labels etc.) Then on each referenced page have different simpler annotated / logo / page number overlays thus keep a large file as optimal.

[image]

```
%PDF-1.7
%Book
2 0 obj <</Pages 3 0 R/Type/Catalog>> endobj
3 0 obj <</Count 15/Kids[4 0 R 5 0 R 6 0 R 7 0 R 8 0 R 9 0 R 10 0 R 11 0 R 12 0 R 13 0 R 14 0 R 15 0 R 16 0 R 17 0 R 18 0 R]/Type/Pages>> endobj
4 0 obj <</MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Parent 3 0 R/Resources<<>>/Type/Page/Contents 19 0 R>> endobj
5 0 obj <</MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Parent 3 0 R/Resources<<>>/Type/Page/Contents 19 0 R>> endobj
6 0 obj <</MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Parent 3 0 R/Resources<<>>/Type/Page/Contents 19 0 R>> endobj
7 0 obj <</MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Parent 3 0 R/Resources<<>>/Type/Page/Contents 19 0 R>> endobj
8 0 obj <</MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Parent 3 0 R/Resources<<>>/Type/Page/Contents 19 0 R>> endobj
9 0 obj <</MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Parent 3 0 R/Resources<<>>/Type/Page/Contents 20 0 R>> endobj
10 0 obj <</MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Parent 3 0 R/Resources<<>>/Type/Page/Contents 20 0 R>> endobj
11 0 obj <</MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Parent 3 0 R/Resources<<>>/Type/Page/Contents 20 0 R>> endobj
12 0 obj <</MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Parent 3 0 R/Resources<<>>/Type/Page/Contents 20 0 R>> endobj
13 0 obj <</MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Parent 3 0 R/Resources<<>>/Type/Page/Contents 20 0 R>> endobj
14 0 obj <</MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Parent 3 0 R/Resources<<>>/Type/Page/Contents 21 0 R>> endobj
15 0 obj <</MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Parent 3 0 R/Resources<<>>/Type/Page/Contents 21 0 R>> endobj
16 0 obj <</MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Parent 3 0 R/Resources<<>>/Type/Page/Contents 21 0 R>> endobj
17 0 obj <</MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Parent 3 0 R/Resources<<>>/Type/Page/Contents 21 0 R>> endobj
18 0 obj <</MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Parent 3 0 R/Resources<<>>/Type/Page/Contents 21 0 R>> endobj
19 0 obj <</Length 118>>
stream
q
/GS0 gs 1 0 0 1 150 750 cm 0 g BT /F0 72 Tf 1 0 0 1 0 0 Tm [(Page     )] TJ 1 0 0 1 0 -100 Tm [(    A 1  )] TJ ET
Q

endstream
endobj

20 0 obj <</Length 0>>
stream
endstream
endobj

21 0 obj <</Length 118>>
stream
q
/GS0 gs 1 0 0 1 150 750 cm 0 g BT /F0 72 Tf 1 0 0 1 0 0 Tm [(Page     )] TJ 1 0 0 1 0 -100 Tm [(    B 1  )] TJ ET
Q

endstream
endobj

xref
0 22
0000000001 65536 f 
0000000021 00002 f 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000060 00000 n 
0000000205 00000 n 
0000000307 00000 n 
0000000409 00000 n 
0000000511 00000 n 
0000000613 00000 n 
0000000715 00000 n 
0000000817 00000 n 
0000000920 00000 n 
0000001023 00000 n 
0000001126 00000 n 
0000001229 00000 n 
0000001332 00000 n 
0000001435 00000 n 
0000001538 00000 n 
0000001641 00000 n 
0000001744 00000 n 
0000001913 00000 n 
0000001961 00000 n 

trailer
<</Size 22/Root 2 0 R>>
startxref
2130
%%EOF
```

If planned correctly, even Windows CMD without use of runtime libraries can add the two (KNOWN structure) source pages into a batched system to loop 100s of variants, by just adjusting maths of last 2 xrefs and startxref (3 simple altered file size values).

For comparison I ran same pages through **cpdf** as answered by @JohnWhitington and compensating for the usual random numbering a program will use for threading buffered objects etc. it produced an almost identical optimised file. The difference is cpdf will then compress  the file (it also has a standalone PDF compressor). Thus will be highly optimised in this case.

```
%PDF-1.7
7 0 obj  <</Pages 1 0 R/Names 13 0 R/Type/Catalog>> endobj
1 0 obj  <</Type/Pages/Kids[10 0 R 3 0 R 9 0 R 22 0 R 20 0 R 21 0 R 12 0 R]/Count 15>> endobj
10 0 obj <</Type/Pages/Kids[6 0 R 18 0 R 14 0 R 23 0 R 5 0 R]/Count 5/Parent 1 0 R>> endobj
6 0 obj  <</Type/Page/Parent 10 0 R/Resources<<>>/MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Rotate 0/Contents[17 0 R]>> endobj
18 0 obj <</Type/Page/Parent 10 0 R/Resources<<>>/MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Rotate 0/Contents[17 0 R]>> endobj
14 0 obj <</Type/Page/Parent 10 0 R/Resources<<>>/MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Rotate 0/Contents[17 0 R]>> endobj
23 0 obj <</Type/Page/Parent 10 0 R/Resources<<>>/MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Rotate 0/Contents[17 0 R]>> endobj
5 0 obj  <</Type/Page/Parent 10 0 R/Resources<<>>/MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Rotate 0/Contents[17 0 R]>> endobj
3 0 obj  <</Type/Page/Parent 1 0 R/Resources<<>>/MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Rotate 0>> endobj
9 0 obj  <</Type/Page/Parent 1 0 R/Resources<<>>/MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Rotate 0>> endobj
22 0 obj <</Type/Page/Parent 1 0 R/Resources<<>>/MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Rotate 0>> endobj
20 0 obj <</Type/Page/Parent 1 0 R/Resources<<>>/MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Rotate 0>> endobj
21 0 obj <</Type/Page/Parent 1 0 R/Resources<<>>/MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Rotate 0>> endobj
12 0 obj <</Type/Pages/Kids[8 0 R 15 0 R 2 0 R 4 0 R 11 0 R]/Count 5/Parent 1 0 R>> endobj
8 0 obj  <</Type/Page/Parent 12 0 R/Resources<<>>/MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Rotate 0/Contents[19 0 R]>> endobj
15 0 obj <</Type/Page/Parent 12 0 R/Resources<<>>/MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Rotate 0/Contents[19 0 R]>> endobj
2 0 obj  <</Type/Page/Parent 12 0 R/Resources<<>>/MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Rotate 0/Contents[19 0 R]>> endobj
4 0 obj  <</Type/Page/Parent 12 0 R/Resources<<>>/MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Rotate 0/Contents[19 0 R]>> endobj
11 0 obj <</Type/Page/Parent 12 0 R/Resources<<>>/MediaBox[0 0 595.276 841.89]/Rotate 0/Contents[19 0 R]>> endobj

17 0 obj <</Length 118>> stream
q /GS0 gs 1 0 0 1 150 750 cm 0 g BT /F0 72 Tf 1 0 0 1 0 0 Tm [(Page     )] TJ 1 0 0 1 0 -100 Tm [(    A 1  )] TJ ET Q
endstream
endobj

13 0 obj <<>> endobj

19 0 obj <</Length 118>> stream
q /GS0 gs 1 0 0 1 150 750 cm 0 g BT /F0 72 Tf 1 0 0 1 0 0 Tm [(Page     )] TJ 1 0 0 1 0 -100 Tm [(    B 1  )] TJ ET Q
endstream
endobj

16 0 obj <</Producer(cpdf non-commercial use only. To buy: http://coherentpdf.com/)>> endobj

xref
0 24
0000000000 65536 f 
0000000016 00000 n 
0000000110 00000 n 
0000000224 00000 n 
0000000320 00000 n 
0000000434 00000 n 
0000000548 00000 n 
0000000662 00000 n 
0000000721 00000 n 
0000000835 00000 n 
0000000931 00000 n 
0000001024 00000 n 
0000001139 00000 n 
0000001231 00000 n 
0000001253 00000 n 
0000001368 00000 n 
0000001483 00000 n 
0000001577 00000 n 
0000001746 00000 n 
0000001861 00000 n 
0000002030 00000 n 
0000002127 00000 n 
0000002224 00000 n 
0000002321 00000 n 

trailer
<</Size 24/Info 16 0 R/Root 7 0 R/ID[<24144D325DBB2AB443EEF008B7D2132A><897652022480A9B8C699FF5D4F19991F>]>>
startxref
2436
%%EOF
```

Due to minor differences in such a small scale test, we see cpdf=2,999 bytes while mine uncompressed could be 2,634 bytes or smaller (without producer info / nesting etc.) However the bigger the sources the better the reduction by using cpdf compressed output, thus I would consider that for production use.

Comment: Very interesting approach: working with PDF as text files and not Python Objects. I will look into this !